# How to Get Coordinates of line in svg after certain distance in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have searched a lot in the SO and google but couldn't find a solution for my specific problem.

I am creating a triangle with the help of three lines in svg. I have no problem creating it but now I also want to show angle arc between the sides. Just few inches above the vertex where two lines are merging. This is the path that I am using to create angle kinda arc using path

```
<path d="M324,141 A50,50 0 0,1 336,164" stroke="#ef00ff" stroke-width="3" fill="none"></path>
```

I have x and y for the vertex.
Three lines I am using have name as line1,line2 and line3
The trianlge being made with mouse move and down events. So its dynamic thats why I have to get the coordinates just few inches away from the vertex in any of the two lines so that I can put them in my arc path.

If anyone likes to know html for triangle let me know. Its just three lines connecting each other.

I am not that much experienced but still learning.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a drawing example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @perellorodrigo Please look at this figure. I just want a arc like that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Triangle.Equilateral.svg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it for one vertex [1]. You will need to loop the `pts` array and do the same for each point.

please read the comments in my code.

```js
//the radius for the pink arc
let r = 15;
//the points to draw the triangle
 let pts = [
   [2.75,-45],[38.97,22.5],[-38.97,22.5]
 ]
 
 //calculate the angle of the first line
 let dx1 = pts[0][0] - pts[1][0];
 let dy1 = pts[0][1] - pts[1][1];
 let a1 = Math.atan2(dy1,dx1);
 //calculate the move to point for the arc 
 let p1 = {
   x:pts[1][0]+r*Math.cos(a1),
   y:pts[1][1]+r*Math.sin(a1)
 }
  //calculate the angle of the second line
 let dx2 = pts[2][0] - pts[1][0];
 let dy2 = pts[2][1] - pts[1][1]; 
 let a2 = Math.atan2(dy2,dx2)
  //calculate the end point for the arc 
  let p2 = {
   x:pts[1][0]+r*Math.cos(a2),
   y:pts[1][1]+r*Math.sin(a2)
 }
  //build the d attribute for the arc
  let d = `M${p1.x},${p1.y}A${r},${r} 0 0 0 ${p2.x},${p2.y}`
  //set the d attribute for the arc
  arc.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d)
```

```css
svg{border:solid;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 90" width="200">
  
<polygon id="poly" points="2.75,-45 38.97,22.5 -38.97,22.5" stroke="black" fill="none"></polygon>
  
<path id="arc"  stroke="#ef00ff" stroke-width="3" fill="none"></path>

</svg>
```

Comment: Although I am using lines to create a triangle but I think in my case your solution should work with a little bit of modification. I'll try and let you know. Thank you. I'm accepting it as answer.

Comment: Just want to let you know that I just tried it and it worked at first shot. Thank you.